# How to install font in a website in html css?

Tags: html, css

I wanna make a website with a font named `SutonnyMJ.TTF` (in Bangla). I tried many resources, but i failed to do this.

i use `@font-face { font-family: SutonnyMJ; src: url('../fonts/SutonnyMJ.TTF'); }`

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SutonnyMJ';
    src: url('../fonts/SutonnyMJ-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/SutonnyMJ-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/SutonnyMJ-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/SutonnyMJ-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/SutonnyMJ-webfont.svg#BebasNeueRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

but they does not work that i want.

Is there anyone to help me please, How can i solve this?

Comment: This ` url('../fonts/*');` implies that you have downloaded the font's files into a directory fonts. Have you done that?

Comment: Yes i've downloaded the font files and it is in a directory named fonts

Comment: “Does not work” is not a problem description. Show a complete HTML + CSS document that reproduces the issue, state explicitly what does not work (expected vs. actual rendering), and identify the source of the font.

Comment: The site is responsive that's why i have to show it to any kind of smartphone. But the font does not support in the smartphone what i use in my site. that's why i need to know how can i do that...

Answer (score 4):

you can  probably remove a couplke lines from there and remove legacy support your site will probably work fine with just this

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'SutonnyMJ';
   src: url('../fonts/SutonnyMJ-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/SutonnyMJ-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

With @font-face you loaded in a custom font but you aren't using it yet

You still have to apply it to your website

```
body {
    font-family: 'SutonnyMJ', sans-serif;
}
```